# Is it possible to take input from a file in NotesSQL

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

For example I have to run a query to fetch data for a list of part numbers.

The list is very big say 1000. So I do not want to give all the part numbers in the query instead want to take it from a file say .txt or .xls

Is It possible with Notes SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Why use Notes SQL to import data from a text file into Notes? Just write a Lotusscript agent that does the import.

Comment: I need to use Notes SQL to export data from Notes DB, whereas I need to give input to my SQL query with a list of values.

Like: 
 "SELECT * from parts where partno IN <read lines from file parts.txt>"

Answer (score 0):

Notes SQL is just a driver that maps SQL queries onto Notes and Domino databases, views, and documents. It's up to you to construct the queries and run them somehow.

There's nothing in the syntax of NotesSQL that can take input from files.

If the program that you are using to generate and run the Notes SQL queries has the ability to read files and use the contents of a file to modify the query before giving it to NotesSQL, then the answer is yes, it's possible to do what you want with Notes SQL.

Comment: I am not using any program to generate queries, directly working on Notes SQL.
OPENROWSET - Function used in SQL to read  input from a file but it in NoteSQL these kind of functions are not recognized. So do we have any alternate?

Comment: You can't run any NotesSQL query without some sort of program to submit it. You must be using a command shell or a database tool of some sort. If the capabilities of that program include reading files, then you can do this. Otherwise, no you can't - because NotesSQL syntax does not include any features that deal with files.

Comment: In SQL we can use OPENROWSET with bulk like below to read input file. whereas, its needs a format file which can be created using bcp utility. But for NotesSQL how to create the format file....

select
    E.emplayeeID, E.Salary
from
    employees E
    JOIN
    OPENROWSET (
             BULK 'c:\myfile.txt',
             FORMATFILE = 'c:\myfileformat.txt'
    ) B ON E.name  = B.name

Comment: Yes, you can use that in Microsoft SQL Server because the local driver for T-SQL supports it. There is no equivalent supported by the NotesSQL driver. You will have to use the capabilities of your shell, database tool, or whatever other type of program you are using in order to read the file, create the appropriate SQL syntax and submit it.

Answer (score 0):

You have it all backwards.  NotesSQL lets you query (pull data out of) a Notes database (.nsf) using ODBC.  That way any software that can connect via ODBC has access to Notes data.  It doesn't allow importing data into Notes.  To get the data into Notes you'll need to either write a script or use something like IBM Enterprise Integrator (IEI, formerly LEI, formerly formerly Notes Pump.)

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to get data into Notes. I think he wants to construct a query like "SELECT * from parts where partno IN <read lines from file parts.txt>" . He can't do that either, but whatever scripting engine or programming language he's using to create and execute the SQL may be able to read from a file and construct an appropriate query.

Comment: I agree, although his question is unclear to me, that's why I replied as I did.